# Assigning method arguments to proper registers

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reimplement existing closed-source armv7 application written in C++ and Qt5. This application calls functions from external library (also without sources). There are no headers, so I made incomplete headers from library symbol list (`nm -CD libExternal.so`). I am having problems calling specific function that takes `char const *` as an argument: `nm::Do(char const*)`. Here is how it is called in original application (ghidra listing):

```asm
...
00212c0e 06 95           str        r5,[sp,#local_20]
00212c10 3c f7 ee fd     bl         FUN_001706f0        ->some qt string shenanigans
00212c14 24 f6 52 ea     blx        libExternal.so::nm::Dog::GetInstance      nm::Dog* GetInstance(void)
00212c18 01 46           mov        r1,r0
00212c1a 9d f8 10 00     ldrb.w     r0,[sp,#local_28]
00212c1e 06 9a           ldr        r2,[sp,#local_20]
00212c20 10 f0 01 0f     tst        r0,#0x1
00212c24 02 a8           add        r0,sp,#0x8
00212c26 08 bf           it         eq
00212c28 46 f0 01 02     orr.eq     r2,r6,#0x1
00212c2c 24 f6 4c ea     blx        libExternal.so::nm::Dog::Dig   undefined Dig(char *)
```

I *assume* that this *may* be equal to following code:

```cpp
const char* direction = "down"
nm::Dog* dog = nm::Dog::GetInstance();
nm::Hole* hole = dog->Dig(direction);
```

That code compiles into (see compilation options below):

```asm
000109fa ff f7 f2 ee     blx        libExternal.so::nm::Dog::GetInstance  undefined GetInstance(void)
000109fe 28 61           str        r0,[r5,#0x10]
00010a00 0b 49           ldr        r1=>s_down_00010a84,[DAT_00010a30]    = "down"
00010a02 ff f7 fa ee     blx        libExternal.so::nm::Dog::Dig          nm::Hole* Dig(char *)
```

As you can see, there is difference in how arguments are passed: `this` is in `r0`, parameter in `r1`.

`nm::Dog::Dig` expects parameter to be passed in `r2`, `this` in `r1` and returns `nm::Hole` in `r0`.
Disassembly:

```asm
00014a94 2d e9 f0 47     push       {r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,lr}
00014a98 03 af           add        r7,sp,#0xc
00014a9a 84 b0           sub        sp,#0x10
00014a9c 80 46           mov        r8,r0
00014a9e 2b 48           ldr        r0,[DAT_00010d3c]
00014aa0 0d 46           mov        r5,r1               <- this
00014aa2 14 46           mov        r4,r2               <- param
...
00014ac0 4c 20           movs       r0,#0x4c
00014ac2 fe f7 a8 ee     blx        <EXTERNAL>::operator.new  void * operator.new(uint r0) -> nm::Hole created
```

I've taken a look into [ABI](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst#parameter-passing):

`A double-word sized type is passed in two consecutive registers (e.g., r0 and r1, or r2 and r3). The content of the registers is as if the value had been loaded from memory representation with a single LDM instruction.`

##### Is there a known way to place arguments into proper registers?

Maybe size of nm::Dog should be bigger so compiler will place `this` into r0 and r1?

###### Compilation options:

I am using clang 7 (upgrade is not possible due to incompability with libExternal), compilation options:

```shell
-O2 \
-mthumb \
-target arm-linux-gnueabihf \
-std=c++11 \
-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now \
-frtti \
-fstack-protector-all \
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

libExternal.so: `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV)`

Comment: That looks like your `Dig` does not return a pointer, it returns an object value which is passed back using a hidden first argument.

Comment: Correct! I also had to add byte padding to `nm::Hole` class definition. Now compiler thinks that `Hole` deserves it's own register. Padding results in segfault later (empty bytes istead of expected code), but it's well beyond initialization point.